# can virtualbox be used to access a locked website without being tracked and without getting detected of using a virtual machine?

Tags: access-control, anonymity, virtualbox

I need to open a website where access is denied in my country. I would like to know if virtualbox can be used to solve this issue. my concern is if they can detect that I am using a virtual machine. if yes, is there any way to hide my location and not being detected of using the VM?

Comment: Who blocks you? The website, or your goverment? How is the block implemented? What do you think will change when you use a VM?

Comment: Questions by @vidarlo are important. This is an X Y problem. Try to outline more detail about the problem you are trying to solve, then we can answer questions about your proposed solution

Comment: thank you guys for your replies! the website itself blocked the access, not the government. I mentioned virtuabox because I thought It uses a server that would show a different location. The block is due to my location because when I travel abroad, I can access it normally. I need to find a way to hide my location. I tried VPN but didn't work.

Comment: A virtual machine _on your real machine_ is still on your machine and doesn't help. A virtual machine _on a real machine provided by someone somewhere else_ is somewhere else and may help; this is often called VPS = Virtual Private Server or nowadays just 'cloud'. Examples: AWS, MS Azure, GCP, DigitalOcean, etc. It doesn't matter which of the many VM technologies you use (VirtualBox, VMWare, Xen, HyperV, KVM, etc) only where the underlying real machine is.

Answer (score 2):

No, because virtual box just nests another computer inside the computer you are already using. It still uses the same network to connect to the website you want to access and will be subject to the same controls and monitoring as the host machine. Whether your use of a virtual box VM will be visible on the network / how you prevent a forensic examination of your computer revealing it has or had virtual box installed are more complex questions but I believe a discussion of these would be significantly beyond your current technical abilities.

Answer (score 2):

You need a vpn or proxy in a different country: the most common are ones sold to non-Americans to access US Netflix, exactly the same use case as yours.

Ordinary "work" vpns are not helpful in this case: work's IP addresses are likely to be in the same country as you are (;-))